# Dynamic Material Autocomplete Options With Type ahead

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-material

I am attempting to use the material autocomplete component to create multiple form fields within a page. These form fields need to have type ahead functionality so I'm utilizing the example on materials site for adding a custom filter. Everything is working as expected until I try to make an autocomplete update it's options based on another fields selection. The type ahead works correctly in both fields until I select an option in the first field. Once I do this the filtering by type ahead no longer works in the second field.

From what I've read, it seems as though I might be finalizing the observable for the second filtered options when I update its options after selecting one of the first fields options which would be causing the valueChanges observable to stop firing.

I haven't seen any examples of this type of capability, it seems that in most cases dynamic options based on other field values are implemented without the type ahead capability. Is something like this not possible?

See the below stackblitz for an example. Try type ahead in both fields (they should filter just fine). Then select an option from the first field. Try to type ahead again in the second field, it will no longer filter the options).
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lanw1g

Comment: Accept the answer if you find it working correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second field is not filtering the values because you are not mapping new values again..

You are doing it on `ngInit`. You should do the same on `numberSelected` method also.

Just add below Code in `numberSelected` method

```
this.alphaOptions = ['Alpha Two', 'Bravo Two'];

this.filteredAlphaOptions = this.alpha.valueChanges
  .pipe(
    startWith(''),
    map(val => this.filterAlpha(val))
  );
```

Test it [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lanw1g-48jbue?file=app%2Fautocomplete-filter-example.ts)

Enjoy!

Comment: This is exactly what was needed, thank you for your help!